# Django Python runserver error: Project is using Twilio for surveys

Tags: python, django, exception, twilio

I'm currently working on a project that uses Twilio to have an automated survey. I'm trying `python manage.py runserver` and I get the following results:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 23, 2017 - 12:15:51
Django version 1.11, using settings 'vizeserver.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x04406FA8
>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\uti
ls\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\cor
e\management\commands\runserver.py", line 147, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\con
trib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
    handler = super(Command, self).get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\cor
e\management\commands\runserver.py", line 68, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\cor
e\servers\basehttp.py", line 47, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\uti
ls\module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py",
line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\Documents\Development\TwilioSurvey\vizeserver\vizeserver\wsgi.py", lin
e 16, in <module>
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\cor
e\wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    return WSGIHandler()
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 151, in __init__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 82, in load_middleware
    mw_instance = middleware(handler)
TypeError: object() takes no parameters
```

I have looked into my vizeserver.settings and I don't see anything off.
The link for the github is https://github.com/Vize-Programming-Team/web-server. I've been trying to see if there is anything wrong with the middleware but I don't know what's wrong.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your middleware, try changing your `middleware.py` in `auto_survey` to

```
class SMSMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

        response = self.get_response(request)
        args = request.POST or request.GET
        request.is_sms = args and args.get('MessageSid')

        return response
```